# google maps ip address question

Tags: google-maps

I have an ip address i want to locate all the nearest places ip addresses marked with marker in google maps.
How can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this client side, consider using the Google Loader's ClientLocation. It provides IP-based geolocation:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation

I'm not sure what you mean by nearest places, perhaps you'll then want to reverse geocode the latlng returned by google.loader.ClientLocation:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/developers.aspx) to get the location of the IP and the use Google [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to find it's coordinates and place it on a map.